# In Racket, is it possible to have multiple event-handlers in big-bang?

Tags: racket, eventhandler

I am wanting to do two different things at each tick.  Is it possible to have multiple on-tick event handlers in a big-bang environment?

This is what I would like to do:

```
(big-bang world

  (on-draw show-world)

  (on-tick event1 event2 1))
```

or

```
(big-bang world

  (on-draw show-world)

  (on-tick event1 1)

  (on-tick event2 1))
```

Neither of these methods is allowed.  Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the two different tick handler functions deal with the same data? If `world` is a `World`, are those two handler functions both `[World -> World]` functions?

Comment: Sure.  Let's say yes.  I have figured out a way to do it by adding more elements to the structure, but it is really messy.  BTW, I am very new to Racket, so please forgive me for not knowing all the lingo.  I'm trying to make a bunch of games for my granddaughter for Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

What would it mean?

For example, suppose that

```
;; A World is a Nat (a natural number).
```

and here are the two tick handlers:

```
;; advance-by-one : World -> World
(define (advance-by-one w)
  (add1 w))

;; reset-at-ten : World -> World
(define (reset-at-ten w)
  (if (< w 10) w 0))
```

If the current World is `9`, then what would you expect the next World to be? (I can think of two plausible answers; you have to pick one.)

Can you define another function that has the meaning you want and just use that (single) function as the tick handler? (Hint: you should use the two existing handler functions rather than trying to merge their definitions into one big function.)

(If you've made it to ISL:) What if you had three handlers, or four, or ten, that you wanted to compose together? Can you design a function that takes a list of handlers and produces a single handler function?

Comment: What I am struggling with is the following:
I want an image (a basket) to move with the posn-x of the mouse AND I want an event to happen when the basket is in the same location as another image (a falling butterfly) and the mouse button is clicked.

Comment: Ryan, I would say 0.

Comment: Originally, this was an on-tick question, because things were moving in time, but I couldn't figure it out, and I've now tried to do it with the mouse.

Ryan asked, "Can you design a function that takes a list of handlers and produces a single handler function?" and I guess that is what I'm asking how to do.

EDIT: Still hoping someone can possibly provide an example of a function that takes a list of handlers and produces a single handler function. Thanks!