# Can you use 2 on-tick functions on a big-bang?

Tags: racket

Can you use 2 on-tick functions on 1 big bang? 1 Running at a default pace and the other a user-defined speed.

Comment: This question might be related: [_Is it possible to have multiple event-handlers in big-bang?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663171/in-racket-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-event-handlers-in-big-bang)

Comment: This might also be related: [_Making a game go faster as time goes by by increasing tick rate?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356735/rackets-big-bang-framework-making-a-game-go-faster-using-tick-rate)

Comment: Yes the question is related but its not answered tho

Answer (score 0):

No. Providing more than one "on-tick" clause to big-bang results in an error: "big-bang: duplicate on-tick clause".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have two time-based behaviors running at different speeds, both controlled by the same `on-tick` function.

For example, the two functions:

- `walk`, which ticks every 5/10 seconds
- `run`, which ticks every 2/10 second

Where `run` ticks at more than twice the speed of `walk`.

To do this, you set your "actual" tick speed to the "greatest common denominator" of the two, which in this case is every 1/10 second. Then you have to make sure `run` is called on every "actual" tick, and `walk` is called on every-other "actual" tick.

```
(define (actual-tick w)
  ???)

(big-bang ???
  [on-tick actual-tick 1/10]
  ...)
```

How do you determine whether `actual-tick` should call `walk` or not? It should be called exactly 1/5 of the time, rotating between "on" "off" "off" "off" "off" regularly.

How do you determine whether `actual-tick` should call `run` or not? It should be called 1/2 of the time, alternating between "on" "off".

To do this you need to keep track of two numbers:

- The number of ticks since the last "walk"
- The number of ticks since the last "run"

These become the two fields in a structure in your world-state.

```
(struct ticks-since [run walk])
```

When to call "walk"? When the `ticks-since-walk` is 5.

```
(define (tick-walk? s)
  (<= 5 (ticks-since-walk s)))
```

When to call "run"? When the `ticks-since-run` is 2.

```
(define (tick-run? s)
  (<= 2 (ticks-since-run s)))
```

And finally the `actual-tick` function needs to call these.

```
(define (actual-tick s)
  (cond
    [(and (tick-walk? s) (tick-run? s))
     ;; call and reset both
     (... walk ...
          run ...
          (ticks-since 0 0) ...)]
    [(tick-walk? s)
     ;; call and reset walk, increment run
     (... walk ...
          (ticks-since 0 (add1 (ticks-since-run s))) ...)]
    [(tick-run? s)
     ;; call and reset run, increment walk
     (... run ...
          (ticks-since (add1 (ticks-since-walk s)) 0) ...)]
    [else
     ;; don't call walk or run, but increment both ticks-since counters
     (... (ticks-since (add1 (ticks-since-walk s))
                       (add1 (ticks-since-run s))) ...)]))
```